# One Page parallax levels/layers

Tags: parallax

Not sure where to look for an answer, but here's my quest:

http://www.mobiliteitsvisie.nl/

On this site I've made a one page parallax, but when scrolling the main text moves underneath the menubar, but the headers (h3 & h4) seem to move over it...
But where would I need to adjust this? In the .css or in the .js file?
Thanks in advance!

Ruud

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're problem is with the style you need to make a change to the CSS.

In your case you want to get the menu on top of all other objects. Just give the menu container a large `z-index`.

Comment: I've tried to accept both your answers because yo offer the same solution, but strangely enough I cannot...

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css file:

```
header {
    z-index: 100; 
}
```

> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
>
> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.
>
> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Comment: I did, I've ticked it a few times as 'accepted', but it doesn't seem to work on the iPad-app!? @Adam Sinclair

Answer (score 0):

Additional question about the same site. When scrolling through the site, the menu-item should change with every slide it passes. At this moment the last clicked menu-item is highlighted, even when scrolling through to the several slides. Is there an easy way to make that work in CSS? Or would that be possible by just adding a *jQuery.nav.js* to the *index.html*?

Comment: You should ask a new question in stack overflow ;). Besides that, I would suggest you to use javascript or jquery for that.